# Dependent fields

Tags: 7

I have 3 content types; `team`, `player` and `game`. When adding a new game, I would like user to first select team, and have the player list loaded only for that selected team. Is there a module that would do it? Thank you!

Comment: There's no module as far as I know that will solve this problem for you but there are quite a few code examples online, including this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158744/drupal-7-best-practice-for-a-dynamic-select-list-in-drupal-7

Comment: if you're using a form, at `validate form`  validate the `team` then load what is selected from the DB using ajax.